# Floated element does not slide when my div slides, instead it snaps, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the slide toggle function in my code to slide two div's. It works fine but when I click on the `#toggleDiv`, it does not come along with the `#panel` div. Which means the #toggleDiv came to the position fastly and then `#panel` div reach that position slowly.I need to set the `#toggleDiv` come equally with the `#panel` div.

```
$("#panel").toggle("slide", {direction:'right'}, 500);
```

here is my [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3DpfJ/137/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  $('#toggleDiv').click(function(){
          $('#panel').animate({width: 'toggle'});
  });
```

Check the working JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/3DpfJ/162/